# What good web file management systems do you use?

Tags: file, filesystems, system

I am looking for a web based file management system and have the following requirements:

- Deal with the huge size of storage

  Permissions on the files according to association groups

  Tagging on files

  Search engine

Is there a service that you can recommend?

Comment: sorry tharkun, stepped on your toes

Comment: no problem, your edit is nicer ;)

Comment: I think the question might get a better response on superuser and have tagged and voted as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your own file management system i would recommend http://www.alfresco.com

Comment: online service without your own app hosting ?

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint, just use the WSS 3.0 that comes for free with a Windows Server license.

One of the best features in WSS is document management, including versioning. Since SharePoint supports document level access out of the box, you should be able to set up a very nice system using the out-of-the-box functionality.
The search functionallity also handles the item level security so if search locates documents that the current user will not be able to access, they will be trimmed out of the result set :-)